# How to integrate this irrational function?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> **Evaluate**
>
> $$ \int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{ax+b} \ dx $$

where $a, b  \in  \mathbb{R}$

I don't know how to solve this.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trigonometric substitution seems to be the obvious way, $x=\sin t$ for example, and then use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution to make the expression rational

Comment: @YuriyS Can't we do something more direct and algebraic?

Comment: Henry, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution is another way, though the first one I suggested is better in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $$x=\sin(u),\mathrm dx=\cos(u)\mathrm du$$ then you will get
$$\int\frac{\cos^2(u)}{a\sin(u)+b}\mathrm du$$ and now use $$s=\tan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$$ and $$\mathrm ds=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\mathrm du$$

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in a comment:

$$x=\sin t$$

---

$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{ax+b} \ dx=\int \frac{\cos^2 t}{a \sin t+b}dt=$$

---

$$\tan (t/2)=u$$

$$\sin t=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$$

$$\cos t=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

$$dt=\frac{2du}{1+u^2}$$

---

$$=2 \int \frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(1+u^2)^3 \left(\frac{2 a u}{1+u^2}+b \right)}du=\frac{2}{b} \int \frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(1+u^2)^2 \left(u^2+2\frac{a}{b}u+1 \right)}du$$

Now we could use partial fractions on the resulting rational function.

---

Euler substitution on the initial expression could lead to something better, but I haven't tried it.